# SQL Server (2012): filling up NULL colums with lower filled values

Tags: t-sql

I was wondering if the following transformation is possible:

I have 2 resultsets combined in a `UNION`. They have 1 column that they share.

```
Group    Value#1 Value#2

A        Red     NULL
A        Blue    NULL
A        Green   NULL
A        NULL    Sweet
B        Red     NULL
B        NULL    Sweet
B        NULL    Sour
```

Can this result be transformed so that *within the group* (A, B) every non nullable value in column `value#2` is shifted up to the first available spot?

Wanted result:

```
Group    Value#1 Value#2

A        Red     Sweet
A        Blue    NULL
A        Green   NULL
B        Red     Sweet
B        NULL    Sour
```

Best regards,

Rick

Comment: What is your desired result?  It will help us better understand your example.

Comment: This should be a job from another layer of your app than db layer.

Comment: @Crono There is no evidence in the question that this for an n-tiered application.

Comment: The problem is that you assume your rows to be in a certain order. Relational database systems do not guarantee that.

Comment: @Khan I reformulated my comment but IMHO tier != layer.

Comment: What I mean to say by that: your problem is a symptom of flaws in your database design.